# Javax.rowset: where I can download that jar?

Tags: java, android, blob, javax

I'm trying to insert a Byte array in my database: I need to convert in a Blob, and I saw javax.sql.rowset.serial.serialclob.

However, I can't find it on the web, neither in my Android Studio. Where I can get it?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think that using `javax.sql` on Android is a good decision in the first place?

Comment: I didn't see any other solution, it was the easiest one for me

Comment: If you are using Android's SQLite, use the dedicated classes for that (e.g., `SQLiteDatabase`). If you are using some hosted database, have your app talk to a Web service that talks to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick look showed me that the respective class is available in my openjdk8 installation inside a resources.jar file.

You should check if all the jars from your java installation are loaded onto your IDE. If not, maybe reinstall java.

Comment: How can I check it? Everything works fine, except for it, it cannot find the class

Comment: It is actually in the rt.jar file in the jre/lib directory. To check if the class is in the jar, you could use the `jar tf <jar-file>` command on the shell to list all the classes and files that the jar contains.

Comment: installed it, but anything, it gets me every time the same error (it shows me only the rawset() but not SerialBlob...